# Meteor Cordova Status Bar on Hot Code Push

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, cordova-3

On a Meteor 1.0.2 Cordova app running on iOS 8, the iOS status bar overlaps the app (webview), but after a hot code push, the entire app (webview) is moved below the status bar. Sometimes this also occur during a new launch of the app.

What can be done to prevent a hot code push from doing this shift?

Comment: we also faced same kinda issue, where, on hot code push app layout used to change. but we ignored it, as we are not supporting Hot code push on production app. if this is the case please feel to ignore this issue during development\

Comment: But we yet found solution for this, i will be happy see this if any fix on this :)

Comment: What `<meta>` tags, config `<preference>`s, cordova plugins, and javascript StatusBar initialization code (if any) are you using?

Comment: @colllin I have no StatusBar initialization code, no `App.setPreferences`, no additional `<meta>` tags but am using Iron Router. Plugins installed are `cordova:org.apache.cordova.device   0.2.12` and 
`cordova:org.apache.cordova.dialogs  0.2.10`

Comment: Tried using `App.setPreference('StatusBarOverlaysWebView', true);` but that doesnt help.

Comment: I solved this by turning the status bar off altogether

Comment: How do you turn off the status bar exactly?